# How to Change the icon in the grails Address bar

Tags: grails, icons

How can i change the grails icon in the Address bar? please the detail step.

The image format and the size to  and the location or directory of the icon.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about favicon by default its include in main layout

path

`your-app/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp`

in the gsp there is a line which adds favicon

Favicon image is on path

`your-app/web-app/images/favicon.ico`

Hope this helps

Comment: should i resize my picture? or i can use it in any size

Comment: Its better to resize to reduce the size of the image but not mandatory , you can also use http://favicon-generator.org/ to generate a favicon out of the image you have

Comment: thanks man. that should have worked but it is still displaying the grails icon.

Comment: Then may be you are not using default grails project structure you need to share more of your pages special view and the layout.